Computing elliptic periods from modular form
How are the periods of a modular elliptic curve computed as path integrals of its associated normalized weight 2 cusp form on the modular curve? Please provide specific paths for both periods and cite relevant references.

How precisely are you relating periods of $f$ with periods of $E$?

The newform is associated to the full isogeny class of the elliptic curve you start with. The form cannot know which period you wish to obtain, it can only give you the period up to certain rational multiples.
Instead, the period is better calculated directly on the elliptic curve, by integrating along the real points of the elliptic curve the absolute value of the Neron differential, that is $dx/(2y+a_1x+a_3)$ in a global minimal model.

@Kimball Perhaps I should refine my question, but generally I imagine that the modular form should know its elliptic curve's isogeny class through its modular periods.

@ChrisWuthrich Searching for a model for my elliptic curve (or its isogeny class) is what I am after, so computing path integrals on the elliptic curve itself is out of the question (as I don't have a model for it).

Ah. Well that was not clear from your question. You are given the new form and you wish to determine the isogeny class of elliptic curves. That is precisely what was used to create Cremona's tables. The period map determines the set of all periods for all modular symbols (or all closed loops on X_0(N) if you prefer). That gives you one lattice and then you have to check what isogenies are possible.

Section 2.10 and 2.11 in https://johncremona.github.io/book/fulltext/chapter2.pdf
